# Name of vector icon font set on iOS

Tags: ios

On Android we know that the icon set is the Material font icon set from here: https://material.io/icons/

However I cannot find the name for the icon set on iOS. I have seen people say many different things. Some say [Linearicons](https://linearicons.com/), some say [Linecons](https://designmodo.com/linecons-free/) but neither of these really look like iOS official to me.

Does anyone know the name of the official iOS icon font set, and where to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't have an official iOS icon font. It does provide some icons for iOS mockup purposes only on [its official website](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/). For implementation, developers refer to the icons, which are bundled with the system, [in code](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/).

Given the restrictive license of the provided materials, nobody can legally make an icon font out of these icons nor use them elsewhere than on Apple platforms.

Comment: As an alternative, I recommend [Simple Line Icons](http://simplelineicons.com/), though the Share icon leaves something to be desired.

Comment: Alternatively, [Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/) are a good cross-platform choice, even though they're not outline icons. They're used by Google on iOS and the material HIG has [guidelines on platform adaptation](https://material.io/guidelines/platforms/platform-adaptation.html#platform-adaptation-platform-recommendations).

Comment: Thanks to your link I found that ionicons is very similar - http://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an official iOS icon font set, however I know that Apple uses their 'San Francisco' font for their applications. An alternative to this font is 'Roboto.' There are numerous online resources to find iOS icons. Apple does however provide official resources for UI Design, which you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/).

Answer (score 0):

There is not any fixed site or any other official standard or something else for the ios application but, for the line icon and fill icon I mainly used [FLAT ICON](https://www.flaticon.com/) where I can find all types of icons like line icon, fill icon, infographics icon.

One other benefit of using this is is that you can get an icon in **PNG** file, **SVG** file, **PSD** file, **EPS** file. and you can save icon in your collection for future use. Last it gives a wide range of free icons.